# How to understand themes in Sencha Ext JS 6?

Tags: extjs

I've created a sample using Triton theme, but it's menu is not black. When I generate an app with CMD the app with Triton theme has a black menu, like this http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/admin-dashboard/#dashboard
Why are these examples looking different?

Comment: My sample is here: http://codepen.io/rinatoptimus/pen/BKwLrN

Comment: It's because Sencha has customized the Theme for their example.

Comment: I thought this black menu is a standard theme, because a standard app I generate with Cmd has the same menu color as that one in sencha examples.

Answer (score 0):

When you generate a standard app with Sencha Cmd, it populates it with it's own sample app, including css and a custom theme, which is why you see the colors that you do. if you want to know how the triton theme looks with all it's components then visit:

http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/examples/classic/themes/index.html

Comment: Don't you know how  can I change theme in Codepen example to this: http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/admin-dashboard/#dashboard?